# Validate EditText as text is typed to remove setError

Tags: android

I am trying to validate text entry in EditText fields. I have `setErrors` created when no text in entered in a field. The fields are validated when the `Submit` button is pressed.

If a `setError` is thrown for an empty field, then text is typed in the field, the `setError`will disappear when `Submi`t is pressed or when the enter key is pressed in the field - NOT when the user types text in the empty field, then manually taps to another field. The `setErro`r for the first field is still active, even though text has been entered.

I'm thinking `EditText` could be validated as text is typed to fix this issue.
 Is this the correct way to do this?

```
EditText toText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.to);
EditText subjectText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subject);

if (toText.getText().length() == 0) {
    toText.setError("Please enter a valid recipient");
}

else {
    toText.setError(null);
}

if (subjectText.getText().length() == 0) {
    subjectText.setError("Please enter a subject");
}

else {
    subjectText.setError(null);
}
```

So what I'm trying to achieve:

- User forgets to enter text in toText
- User clicks Submit and the setError message appears
- User types text in toText
- User taps subjectText
- toText still displays the setError
- I would like to remove setError in this scenario

toText will remove the setError if:

- User clicks Submit again to revalidate the fields
- User hits enter on the keyboard to advance to the next field

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did not get you completely. Why dont you use something like this:

```
//EditText et;

if(et.getText().length() == 0) {
//the field is empty
}
else {
//perform the action
}
```

alternatively you can use `Regular Expressions` to validate the input

Comment: May be I think you can do `subjectText.setError(null);` at the first line in the `onClick()` of submit `Button`.